# spring.rabbitmq.listener.simple.retry.enabled=true is ignored if I configure manually DirectMessageListenerContainer

Tags: rabbitmq, spring-amqp, spring-annotations, spring-rabbit

I'm trying to activate deadletterqueue on rabbitmq with properties

```
spring.rabbitmq.listener.simple.retry.enabled=true
spring.rabbitmq.listener.simple.retry.max-attempts=10
```

It works fine when I use annotation

```
public class SimpleConsumer {

    @RabbitListener(queues = "messages.queue")
    public void handleMessage(String message){
        throw new RuntimeException(); 
    }
}
```

but if I configure manually MessageListenerContainer, it doesn't work.

Below my configurations:

```
@Bean
SimpleMessageListenerContainer directMessageListenerContainer(
        ConnectionFactory connectionFactory,
        Queue simpleQueue,
        MessageConverter jsonMessageConverter,
        SimpleConsumer simpleConsumer)
{

    return new SimpleMessageListenerContainer(connectionFactory){{
        setQueues(simpleQueue);
        setMessageListener(new MessageListenerAdapter(simpleConsumer, jsonMessageConverter));
       // setDefaultRequeueRejected(false);
    }};

}
```

If I set setDefaultRequeueRejected to true it try to resolve consumer infinite time (if throw exception).

If I set setDefaultRequeueRejected to false it try to resolve consumer one time and then use deadLetterConsumer.

What  @RabbitListener(queues = "messages.queue") do under the hood for use spring.rabbitmq.listener configurations?

below my code on github

https://github.com/crakdelpol/dead-letter-spike.git

see branch "retry-by-configuration"

Answer (score 3):

It adds a retry interceptor to the container's advice chain. See [the documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-amqp/docs/current/reference/html/#retry).

> Spring Retry provides a couple of AOP interceptors and a great deal of flexibility to specify the parameters of the retry (number of attempts, exception types, backoff algorithm, and others). Spring AMQP also provides some convenience factory beans for creating Spring Retry interceptors in a convenient form for AMQP use cases, with strongly typed callback interfaces that you can use to implement custom recovery logic. See the Javadoc and properties of `StatefulRetryOperationsInterceptor` and `StatelessRetryOperationsInterceptor` for more detail.

> ...

```java
@Bean
public StatefulRetryOperationsInterceptor interceptor() {
    return RetryInterceptorBuilder.stateful()
            .maxAttempts(5)
            .backOffOptions(1000, 2.0, 10000) // initialInterval, multiplier, maxInterval
            .build();
}
```

Then add the interceptor to the container `adviceChain`.

**EDIT**

See the documentation I pointed you to; you need to add the recoverer to the interceptor:

> The MessageRecover is called when all retries have been exhausted. The RejectAndDontRequeueRecoverer does exactly that. The default MessageRecoverer consumes the errant message and emits a WARN message.

Here is a complete example:

```java
@SpringBootApplication
public class So67433138Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(So67433138Application.class, args);
    }

    @Bean
    Queue queue() {
        return QueueBuilder.durable("so67433138")
                .deadLetterExchange("")
                .deadLetterRoutingKey("so67433138.dlq")
                .build();
    }

    @Bean
    Queue dlq() {
        return new Queue("so67433138.dlq");
    }

    @Bean
    SimpleMessageListenerContainer container(ConnectionFactory cf) {
        SimpleMessageListenerContainer smlc = new SimpleMessageListenerContainer(cf);
        smlc.setQueueNames("so67433138");
        smlc.setAdviceChain(RetryInterceptorBuilder.stateless()
                .maxAttempts(5)
                .backOffOptions(1_000, 2.0, 10_000)
                .recoverer(new RejectAndDontRequeueRecoverer())
                .build());
        smlc.setMessageListener(msg -> {
            System.out.println(new String(msg.getBody()));
            throw new RuntimeException("test");
        });
        return smlc;
    }

    @RabbitListener(queues = "so67433138.dlq")
    void dlq(String in) {
        System.out.println("From DLQ: " + in);
    }

}
```

```
test
test
test
test
test
2021-05-12 11:19:42.034 WARN 70667 ---[    container-1] o.s.a.r.r.RejectAndDontRequeueRecoverer : Retries exhausted for message ...
...
From DLQ: test
```

Comment: It seems not working, here my code https://github.com/crakdelpol/dead-letter-spike/commit/38aaa8ab3bc45be7323f66a988276daeb33d58a1

Comment: Have you tried stateless? With stateful you need a message id header so we can look up state.

Comment: `RetryInterceptorBuilder.stateless()...`.

Comment: it work but it doen't use deadletter-queue when number of attempts are exceeded

Comment: The queue has to be configured to route rejected messages to a dead letter exchange.

Comment: yes with .withArgument("x-dead-letter-exchange", DLQ_EXCHANGE), as you can se here https://github.com/crakdelpol/dead-letter-spike/blob/main/src/main/java/it/pipitone/matteo/spike/rabbitmq/configuration/MessagingConfiguration.java

Comment: Read the documentation I pointed you to; I edited my answer with an example.